# AngularJS manual routing with ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS in the client side combined with ExpressJS in the server side.

When pages are loaded in the browser all works fine there: clicks on the various button and differents angular routers are okay.

The problems come when a generated url need to be put in the address bar manually.

Here are the details of this scenario:

1. the server generates a URL (e.g. "http://localhost:9000/details?card=5" and sends it via email
2. I receive the email, open the url from it
3. the browser opens on "/" instead of staying on "/details" internal/client route

On the **details.controller.js** of **details.html** (client side) I can see that the request for card number 5 is sent and arrives to the server (so I am almost sure that the details.html page is loaded) but angular routing must be very quick relocating the user view on "/".

I am not sure on the exact flow, but I am assuming that:

1. click on the link in the email
2. the OS or email client redirect "http://localhost:9000/details?card=5" to the browser
3. the browser receives "http://localhost:9000/details?card=5" and performs a GET to the server
4. the server receives the GET above
5. maybe the server is calling "/index.html" since express static is configured as:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, config.client.path), {
  index: 'index.html',
}))
```

Maybe I am little confusing something, the project is not mine and I have not so many skills in (the very old) AngularJS.

Could someone explain to me how the server could "say" to the client to move on the angular "/detail" route (including the query param *card*)?

Comment: There would have to be an `app.use("/details", ...)` on the server. Is that the case?

Comment: After little time spent to understand the scenario, the issue is about how NodeJS Express can tell Angular to to route on a specific component... if I put localhost:3000/details?card=5 in the address bar, the browser will generate a GET request to the server, which will be served as a sendFile(index.html) to Angular. That explain why I see the home of the Angular components and the Detail component is not show up. I am looking a way make Express be able to serve request pointing to a specific Angular component